# How to get my activate form to work with position relative?

Tags: html, css

I have the following activate form and I am trying to get it to work using position relative instead of absolute because from my understanding, using position relative does not take the form out of normal flow but for some reason, I can't move the form pass a certain section of my page. I can only move it to a certain point and then my form would disappear... Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kumar+One+Outline" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="activate_title">
    <h2>Activate your Membership Plan Here!</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="activate">
    <form class="signup-form" action="token_request.php" method="POST">
        <label>Token:</label>
        <br></br>
        <input type="text" name="token" placeholder="Enter Token">
        <br></br>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <br></br>
        <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Enter User Name">
        <br></br>
        <label id="email">Email Address:</label>
        <br></br>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter E-mail Address">
        <br></br>
        <label id="request">Request Activation For Which Subscriptionplan?</label>
        <br></br>
        <select name="subscription">
        <option value="Primer Level">primer</option>
        <option value="Level 1">Level 1</option>
        <option value="Level 2">Level 2</option>
        <option value="Level 3">Level 3</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Activate Subscriptionplan!</button>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>











<?php

include_once 'footer.php';
?>


and here is my css

div.activate {
  position: relative;
  left: 55em;
  bottom: -40em;
}

div.activate input {
   height: 40px;
   padding: 0px 5%;
   margin-bottom: 4px;
   border-radius: 10px solid black;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #111;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 18em;
   margin-top: 1em;
}

div.activate input::placeholder {
  color: #6A5ACD ;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  left: .5em;
  font-size: 1em;

}

div.activate select {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

div.activate label {
   color:#008000;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   white-space: nowrap;
   position: relative;
   left: -2em;
}

div.activate_title h2{
  position: relative;
  left: 12em;
  top: 5em;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div.activate button {
   width: 50%;
   height: 40px;
   border:none;
   background-color: #222;
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #fff;
   cursor:pointer;
   position: relative;
   top: 40em;
   left: 5em;
   border-radius: 1em;


}

div.activate button:hover {
   background-color: #008000;
   color: #9932CC;
}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a reason why u want to set your form relative instead of static (positions default)?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you want to set your forms Position to `relative` instead of `absolute`. positions default is `static`. i think removing `position: relative` on `div.activate` should do what you are looking for.

```css
div.activate {
  //position: relative; ### remove this ###
  left: 55em;
  bottom: -40em;
}

div.activate input {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px 5%;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 10px solid black;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #111;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

div.activate input::placeholder {
  color: #6A5ACD;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  left: .5em;
  font-size: 1em;
}

div.activate select {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

div.activate label {
  color: #008000;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  left: -2em;
}

div.activate_title h2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12em;
  top: 5em;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div.activate button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #222;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 40em;
  left: 5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

div.activate button:hover {
  background-color: #008000;
  color: #9932CC;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kumar+One+Outline" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="activate_title">
  <h2>Activate your Membership Plan Here!</h2>
</div>
<div class="activate">
  <form class="signup-form" action="token_request.php" method="POST">
    <label>Token:</label>
    <br></br>
    <input type="text" name="token" placeholder="Enter Token">
    <br></br>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <br></br>
    <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Enter User Name">
    <br></br>
    <label id="email">Email Address:</label>
    <br></br>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter E-mail Address">
    <br></br>
    <label id="request">Request Activation For Which Subscriptionplan?</label>
    <br></br>
    <select name="subscription">
      <option value="Primer Level">primer</option>
      <option value="Level 1">Level 1</option>
      <option value="Level 2">Level 2</option>
      <option value="Level 3">Level 3</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Activate Subscriptionplan!</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why but when I set it to position absolute, then I can move my form but I thought that this would take out of the normal flow and it would be best to use position relative?

Comment: I am wondering if position relative should only be used to relate to physical thing because my div.activate is to move the whole form itself and maybe that is why I can't use position relevant for the whole form

Comment: I thought that I can use position relevant for everything?